Can flutter's showModalBottonSheet show dynamic height and then be draggable?
Basically showModalBottomSheet must have some initial height. But then on dragging it, more content should be shown. Is this possible?

DraggableScrollableSheet which is in-built in flutter can be used inside the showModalBottonSheet to achieve this.

Yes it's possible. you can do it with isScrollControlled in showModalBottomSheet like this:
showModalBottomSheet(
   isScrollControlled: true,
   context: context,
   builder: (context) {
   return Wrap();//Your Widgets
 },
)

just set isScrollControlled: true and you can drag your showModalBottomSheet. Hope this helps you.

isScrollControlled sets the screen height to fullscreen. I tried a lot before asking this question, but do you know a way to set the initial height? There is a package for this, but I want to do it without dependencies unless absolutely necessary.

Can you share more information about it and what exactly you want?
